# JS File changes done on WebSphere server not reflecting via dmgr URL

Tags: javascript, websphere, load-balancing, high-availability

I have an application deployed on WAS 9.0.0.6 in clustered mode and access the application via dmgr domain name. Recently, I made some changes to a JS file in the application. Accessing the application via individual IP of the cluster, the changes are reflected. However, if the same application is accessed via the dmgr domain name on the same machine and same browser, the changes are not there and only the previous file is present.
I have tried accessing the application via dmgr IP, but it not accessible. However, I suppose that should not be the way to go to fix this. Request for any inputs, as this is very new to me. Couldn't find much on SFO and other sources as well.

Comment: If you use dmgr, then you are in network deployment.  If the application is updated on the server, then you break the sync between dmgr and the app server.  Any application change must be deployed via the dmgr, to ensure all apps have the same files.  Note also that if you modify in an app server, when a new node sync is done, files are overwritten, using the dmgr content as source.

Comment: Thanks. It was really helpful.